# How to create a new array from current, with changed "id" of all single item

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array

```
const arr = [
  { id: 31241, title: "Campfire Story" },
  { id: 31242, title: "Booting Up" },
  { id: 31243, title: "Hey Boys" },
.......
];
```

How can I create a new array from the current one so that id and index are the same:

```
  const newArr = [
      { id: 0, title: "Campfire Story" },
      { id: 1, title: "Booting Up" },
      { id: 2, title: "Hey Boys" },
    .......
    ];
```

Comment: There has to be a dupetarget for this... Use `map`, and use the index it passes you: `const newArray = arr.map((entry, index) => ({...entry, id: index}));` Or if it's okay to modify the array and objects in place, `forEach`: `arr.forEach((entry, index) => entry.id = index);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` and replace the `id` with the index of the element in array.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 31241, title: "Campfire Story" },
  { id: 31242, title: "Booting Up" },
  { id: 31243, title: "Hey Boys" },
];
const res = arr.map((x, i) => ({...x, id: i}))
console.log(res)
```